# Why are there word differences in Jesus’ teaching on internal defilement?

Tags: mark, textual-criticism

I don’t see any translators note within the realm of “textual criticism” here in Mark 7:21-23 from the NET so I’m confused when compared to the NKJV:

> “For from within, out of the human heart, come evil ideas, sexual
> immorality, theft, murder, adultery, greed, evil, deceit, debauchery,
> envy, slander, pride, and folly. All these evils come from within and
> defile a person.”” ‭‭Mark‬ ‭7:21-23‬ ‭NET‬‬
>
> “For from within, out of the heart of men, proceed evil thoughts,
> adulteries, fornications, murders, thefts, covetousness, wickedness,
> deceit, lewdness, an evil eye, blasphemy, pride, foolishness. All
> these evil things come from within and defile a man.”” ‭‭Mark‬
> ‭7:21-23‬ ‭NKJV‬‬

I do know the NKJV is primarily based on the TR(**Textus Receptus**) & so I am a little confused if the NET is based on a different textual grouping?
**Q**: Why does the NKJV say different words than the NET in this same passage?  (Example: NKJV says “blasphemy” & the NET doesn’t).

Answer (score 3):

The Greek text (UBS5) of Mark 7:21-22 is essentially undisputed.  It reads:

ἔσωθεν γὰρ ἐκ τῆς καρδίας τῶν ἀνθρώπων οἱ διαλογισμοὶ οἱ κακοὶ ἐκπορεύονται, πορνεῖαι, κλοπαί, φόνοι, μοιχεῖαι, πλεονεξίαι, πονηρίαι, δόλος, ἀσέλγεια, ὀφθαλμὸς πονηρός, βλασφημία, ὑπερηφανία, ἀφροσύνη·

The "problem" here between the versions is the translation of the list of sins:

- πορνεῖαι (porneiai) = sexual immorality, fornications
- κλοπαί (klopai) = thefts
- φόνοι (phonoi) = murders
- μοιχεῖαι (moicheiai) = adulteries
- πλεονεξίαι (pleonexiai) = greedinesses, covetousnesses
- πονηρίαι (poneriai) = wickednesses, evils
- δόλος (dolos) = deceit
- ἀσέλγεια (aselgeia) = lewdness, debauchery, sensuality, lasciviousness
- ὀφθαλμὸς πονηρός (ophthalmos poneros) = evil eye (possibly envy??)
- βλασφημία (blasphemia) = blasphemy, slander
- ὑπερηφανία (hyperephania) = pride, arrogance
- ἀφροσύνη (aphrosune) = foolishness, folly

Note that the two lists (UBS5 of ESV & NET etc, vs TR of KJV and NKJV)are the same except the order of the first four is different in the two texts.  Further, the Greek words can have more than one English translation, most notably blasphemy/slander.

Comment: Ah, so just like “porneiai”, the word blasphemy in Greek can have a wide range of meanings.  Gotcha.  +1

Comment: +1 good answer.